# MySQL: counting duplicates after join without filtering/grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I hope this is not a duplicate, I've searched for a while without any useful results.

I have a table of objects (with a primary key) and a table of relations. Each relation references two objects via foreign keys (obj_1 and obj_2). The combination of obj_1 and obj_2 is unique, so I can represent a network of sorts.

Now I want to select points which lie in between at least two other points (e.g. have more than one connection). I achieved this with the following query:

```
select r1.obj_1,  r1.obj_2 as hop, r2.obj_2
from t_relations r1
inner join t_relations r2 on r1.obj_2 = r2.obj_1
```

Now, my problem is that I want to see the number of connections each hop has as well, but **without filtering** (I need all rows selected, so group by is not an option). How can I do this?

---

As requested, some example data. For simplicity I assume that the numbers in t_relations are actual objects.

t_relations

```
ID |  obj_1 | obj_2
 1 |   T1   |   T2
 2 |   T3   |   T2
 3 |   T4   |   T2
 4 |   T4   |   T3
```

expected output:

```
 obj_1 |  hop |  obj_2 | count
  T1   |  T2  |   T3   |   3    # 3 connections with 2
  T3   |  T2  |   T4   |   3
  T4   |  T2  |   T1   |   3
  T4   |  T3  |   T1   |   1    # 1 connection via 3
  T2   |  T4  |   T1   |   1    # 1 connection with 4 in the middle
```

As you can hopefully see, I expect the query to 'traverse' the network, taking all possible routes and omitting duplicates (like 1-2-4 which would be redundant to 4-2-1). I think my query does fulfill this... the count is the problem.

Comment: Can you show example data and expected output?

Comment: Not totally sure what you're asking, but I suspect you need to join with a subquery that uses `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Why not provide an example that isn't "hard to follow"

Comment: Because then there is nothing left to do. I believe in you (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood, each row is a direct connection between two points of an [undirected graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undirected_graph#Undirected_graph), and (according to your query) you want to obtain the number of connections between two points with **one** hop. Am I right? You can achieve this using this query (maybe there is a simpler solution but this one works as specified):

```
select distinct p1, tmp.hop, p2, count from (
    select if(p1 < p2, p1, p2) as p1, hop, if(p1 < p2, p2, p1) as p2 from (
        select r1.obj_1 as p1, r1.obj_2 as hop, r2.obj_2 as p2
        from t_relations r1 inner join t_relations r2 on r1.obj_2 = r2.obj_1
            union
        select r1.obj_2 as p1, r1.obj_1 as hop, r2.obj_2 as p2
        from t_relations r1 inner join t_relations r2 on r1.obj_1 = r2.obj_1
            union 
        select r1.obj_1 as p1, r1.obj_2 as hop, r2.obj_1 as p2
        from t_relations r1 inner join t_relations r2 on r1.obj_2 = r2.obj_2
            union
        select r1.obj_2 as p1, r1.obj_1 as hop, r2.obj_1 as p2
        from t_relations r1 inner join t_relations r2 on r1.obj_1 = r2.obj_2
    ) tmp where p1 <> p2
) tmp inner join (
    select hop, count(*) as count from (
        select distinct p1, hop, p2 from (
            select if(p1 < p2, p1, p2) as p1, hop, if(p1 < p2, p2, p1) as p2 from (
                select r1.obj_1 as p1, r1.obj_2 as hop, r2.obj_2 as p2
                from t_relations r1 inner join t_relations r2 on r1.obj_2 = r2.obj_1
                    union
                select r1.obj_2 as p1, r1.obj_1 as hop, r2.obj_2 as p2
                from t_relations r1 inner join t_relations r2 on r1.obj_1 = r2.obj_1
                    union 
                select r1.obj_1 as p1, r1.obj_2 as hop, r2.obj_1 as p2
                from t_relations r1 inner join t_relations r2 on r1.obj_2 = r2.obj_2
                    union
                select r1.obj_2 as p1, r1.obj_1 as hop, r2.obj_1 as p2
                from t_relations r1 inner join t_relations r2 on r1.obj_1 = r2.obj_2
            ) tmp where p1 <> p2
        ) tmp
    ) tmp group by hop
) tmp2 on tmp.hop = tmp2.hop;
```

Comment: Well, the grouping is nice but the num_connections column always has a 1 inside, even if the hop appears multiple times.

Comment: Then I think I misunderstood. If you have four relations: `1 -> 2`, `2 -> 3`, `1 -> 4` and `4 -> 3`, the query must show that there are 2 connections from 1 to 3 with one hop. Is that right?

Comment: I changed the query so now it does what you specify.

Comment: Unfortunately the num_connections column is still always 1. Please have a look at my updated question if the initial question was not clear enough :)

Comment: You are representing a graph, aren't you? And as I see, it's an undirected graph. Am I right?

Comment: I think this is correct, although I'm not very familiar with graph theory.

Comment: I edited the code, now it is a little complex but it works :)

Comment: What a solution! I would have never gone to such an extent :D thank you so much!  PS: just a minor correction, one of the inner select statements (the 3rd inside both parts) should be select r1.obj_1 as **p1** instead of p2, but it does not make a difference right now.